# Flutter hot reload feature

Tags: flutter, dart, emulation

I was wondering If I could build an app builder with Flutter, so it could be drag and drop widgets, and it hot reload it directly with the emulator, is this possible? Any resources, articles, or videos?

Comment: Do you mean something like FlutterFlow?

Comment: @Mäddin yeah, but how to make the drag and drop feature?